# call Paint event of picturebox from PageLoad in C# causes an error

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I create a **PictureBox** that get lots of point and draws a map for my application ,so these point is read from database ,so when i move the scroll of my **picturebox** to see other part of my map ,the **paint event** is called again ,and my application have to read the points from databse to draw map ,but it doesn't need ,because i read that before ,so reading data from database makes my application to be so slow ,so i try to locate my code in **Paint event** to **Page_load** ,because this transfering makes my code to be run just one time ,
So let me explain my code :

```
private void pictureBoxMetroMap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen pLine = new Pen(Color.White, 2);
            SolidBrush RedBrush = new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cc0000"));
            SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0066ff"));
            SolidBrush greenBrush = new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3db300"));
            SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#fff"));



            SensorRepository objSensorRepository = new SensorRepository();
            List<Sensor> lstSensorLeft = objSensorRepository.GetSensorsLine(1, "Left");

            List<Point> lstPointLeft = new List<Point>();
            foreach (var t in lstSensorLeft)
            {
                Point objPoint = new Point(t.XLocation, t.YLocation);
                lstPointLeft.Add(objPoint);
                Rectangle rectSens = new Rectangle(t.XLocation, t.YLocation, 3, 3);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, rectSens);
                if (t.StationId != null)
                {
                    Rectangle rectEhsansq = new Rectangle(t.XLocation-6, t.YLocation-6, 12, 12);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rectEhsansq);

                    Rectangle rectTrainState = new Rectangle(t.XLocation -3, t.YLocation-3, 7, 7);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(RedBrush, rectTrainState);
                }
            }
            StationRepository ObjStationRepository = new StationRepository();

            List<Sensor> lstSensorRight = objSensorRepository.GetSensorsLine(1, "Right");
            List<Point> lstPointRight = new List<Point>();

            foreach (var t in lstSensorRight)
            {
                Point objPoint = new Point(t.XLocation+30, t.YLocation+30);
                lstPointRight.Add(objPoint);
                Rectangle rectSens = new Rectangle(t.XLocation+30, t.YLocation+30, 3, 3);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, rectSens);
                if (t.StationId!= null)
                {
                    Rectangle rectPosition= new Rectangle(t.XLocation + 24, t.YLocation + 24, 12, 12);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rectPosition);

                    Rectangle rectTrainState = new Rectangle(t.XLocation + 27, t.YLocation + 27, 7, 7);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(RedBrush, rectTrainState);

                }
            }


            e.Graphics.DrawLines(pLine, lstPointLeft.ToArray());
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(pLine, lstPointRight.ToArray());



        }
```

This is **Pain event** of my picturebox that after every scroll movement is called .I need to transfer this code to **page_Load**.I did that but my problem is how can i handle these values :

```
(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
```

Because the page_load doesnt any **PaintEventArgs**  argument.I mean how can i tranfer this code to  **page_load**

My page_load :

```
 private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;


        }
```

Best regards

Comment: Trying to abuse the Paint event does turn it into a Pain event.  You can get a Graphics object from Graphics.FromImage().  So write a DrawPicture(Graphics g) method and move the code into it.  Now you can create a bitmap in your Load event handler, call this method, and, say, assign the PictureBox.Image property.  If you have a need to adjust the map then just do the same thing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't read from a database in OnPaint and you shouldn't draw on the screen in OnLoad.

So divide the work: in OnLoad, fetch and store the data. In OnPaint, draw the cached data.

Comment: Yes you are right ,but i did that before  ,and it works ,but i need to paint my map in page_load because it makes my app to be run so fast ,and i don't need to paint my map every time

Comment: Then draw it to a bitmap. The OnPaint can dan just show (parts of) that bitmap.